# Calculate the frequency of strings(genes) separated by delimiter in each sample

Tags: regex, r, bioinformatics, frequency

I have this dataframe called `mydf`. I want to calculate the frequency of these genes in `Left.Gene.Symbols` and `Right.Gene.Symbols` for each sample and then calculate the cumulative frequency in all samples and get the expected output as shown below.

```
mydf<-structure(c("AMLM12001KP", NA, "1114002", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "1121501", NA, NA, NA, "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "CR1L", "GIGYF2:GIGYF2:GIGYF2:ENPP3", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NTNG1:NTNG1:ENPP3", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "CDC27:CDC27", "NA", "ENPP3", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), .Dim = c(12L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Sample_name", 
    "Left.Gene.Symbols", "Right.Gene.Symbols")))
```

expected output:

```
 Left.Gene.Symbols      Right.Gene.Symbols
    AMLM12001KP

    1114002
    CR1L=1                  CDC27=2
    GIGYF2=3                ENPP3=1
    ENPP3=1

    1121501

    NTNG1=2 
    ENPP3=1

    All_samples

    CR1L=1                  CDC27=2
    GIGYF2=3                ENPP3=1
    NTNG1=2 
    ENPP3=2
```

Comment: if you only change one thing: `lapply(sp, function(x) {` to `lapply(c(sp, total = list(do.call('rbind', sp))), function(x) {` in my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172940/calculate-the-frequency-of-strings-separated-by-delimiter-in-different-section-o/34173395#34173395), then you get these results. are you making any effort?

Comment: @rawr Thanks a lot. Sorry I am a beginner in R. How do you then get the frequncy of individual genes in left and right columns per sample in a dataframe or table format and not in list?

Comment: each element of the list is a table, then you can convert to a data frame as `data.frame(l$`1114002`)` (this was right below in the edit). is there a specific format that you need for something else or are you just looking at the results?

Comment: @rawr I want them to rbind with sample and then all the frequency and then sample and all the frequency associated with it like in the output above.